# Isomorphism,on ${R}^4$

Tags: vector-spaces

> I dont understand what the function is for part (a) such that a mapping from $X\in T_p{R}^4$ to $w(X,-)\in T^{\star}_p{R}^4$ be an isomorfism!.
>    So Consider on ${R}^4=(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2)$ the $2$-form $w=dx_1\wedge dy_1+dx_2\wedge dy_2$  And $T_p{R}^4={R}^4\approx T^{\star}_p{R}^4$ for each $p\in{R}^4$ by means of the canonical basis.
>
> a) Prove that$$X\in T_p{R}^4\mapsto w(X,-)\in T^{\star}_p{R}^4$$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces.

Dear M.B I need to add that:
$w(x,y)=(dx_1\wedge dy_1)(x,y)+(dx_2\wedge dy_2)(x,y)$

hence $w(x,y)=x_1y_2-x_2y_1+x_3y_4-x_4y_3$

so $w(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}-x_1 & x_2 & -x_4 & x_3 \end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\ y_2\\ y_3\\ y_4 \end{bmatrix}$

so $\phi(x)$=$w(x,-)$  and $\phi$ :${R}^4$$ \mapsto$ ${R}^{(\star)4}$

I need to show that :
1) $\phi$ is linear? 
2)$\phi$ is injective?
 3)$\phi$ is surjective?

but I dont Know how??

> b) Give a matrix $J$ of this transformation.
>   (What is ${J}^2$ and the inverse of $J$?)(I mean $\phi$$(e_i)$=$\Sigma$$a_(ij)$${e}^{(\star)}$ which ${a_(ij)}$ `s are coefficient of matrix J what are these coefficients?)

Comment: Dear armin, have you tried to write out $W(X,-)$ explicitly?

Comment: I have been added some usefulle informaitiom

Comment: OK, can you recover the components of X from w(X,-)? Can you use that to show that X->w(X,-) is injective?

Comment: No,I dont know how???

Comment: If $w(X,-) = w(Z,-)$ then $w(X, e_1) = w(Z, e_1) = X_1 = Z_1$. Similarly, $X_2 = Y_2$, etc.

Comment: tank you,for your answer!!

Comment: Do you knw how I can  proof injectivity with use of null space ?I mean that $\phi$ is injective if and only if $N(\phi)$=${0}$

Comment: Sure, assume that $W(X,-) = 0$. Then all the components of x are $0$ by the same argument. Now please try to continue by yourself. This is elementary.

Comment: yes,I did it,but  wat else if $y$=$0$ ?

Comment: How can I proof that $\phi$ is surjective?